# What is max aggregation on a set of word embeddings?

Tags: neural-network, word-embeddings

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07771.pdf) I see:

[image]
[image]

$\mathcal{Q}$ is a set of words.

$\psi_{G^w}$ are word embeddings.

so, $\{\psi_{G^w}(w_t), \forall w_t \in \mathcal{Q}\}$ gives me a set of embeddings for all words in $\mathcal{Q}$.

For example, if I have:

```
Q = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
embedding_gw.shape = (1000, 8) # 1000 words in vocab, embedding size is 8
```

I will get:

```
{
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], #embedding of 'a'
  [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], #embedding of 'b'
  [4,5,3,6,7,8,1,2]  #embedding of 'c'
}
```

The result of $\max\{\psi_{G^w}(w_t), \forall w_t \in \mathcal{Q}\}$ is supposed to be a single vector.

My question is, **how do I get this single $\max$ vector?**

- Do I sum all values in each embedding and pick the largest one?
- Do I pick the $\max$ value of each $i^{th}$ position, creating a completely new vector?
- Do I do something else?

Comment: Linking the paper will definitely help

Comment: @KiriteeGak, this is the paper ;) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07771.pdf
Section 4.2 equation 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is the right one. From the paper:

> In this case, we perform a component-wise max over the start
>   embeddings of all instances of w to obtain the best features across
>   all occurrences of w.

The previous quote can be found a few paragraphs before equation 17, second column, top of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was referring only to equation 15, but makes sense if it is also applicable to equation 17.